# How to make custom input pin code Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme, android-styles

I make project on Kotlin Android. How can i make the same field and same input? It seems to me creating a few edittexts is not good decision
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N5ax.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAqTz.png)

Now i have this decision

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="_ _ _ _ _ _"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/stolzl_regular"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:letterSpacing="0.12"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_input_number"/>
```

but it doesn't work how i heed

Comment: Trying using some library like OTP box something like that it would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to research market for a library which will do this work for you. [AndroidArsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/) or [github.com](https://github.com/search?q=android%20pin%20code&type=repositories) are good places to start.

If you will not find a good library within an hour or two, you will have to implement a custom component. Android has a good documentation on how to do [this](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/custom-components)